# chat.<site> redirects are giving a server error

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, redirection

Previously, if you attempted to visit `chat.<site>.stackexchange.com`, it would redirect to the list of chat rooms for that site. For instance, https://chat.scifi.stackexchange.com would redirect to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=scifi.stackexchange.com.

However, at some point relatively recently this appears to have broken. I now get a server error whenever I try to use this redirect:

[image: transcription below]

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *Runtime Error*
>
> **Description**: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Any chance this could be fixed? Hardly priority, but it'd be nice to have it back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**: I've altered the `/chat` URL on each site to go to the chatroom list, so for `*.stackexchange.com/chat`, you'll be redirected to `https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=*.stackexchange.com` (e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/chat will redirect to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=scifi.stackexchange.com)

Thanks for the feedback, and hope this works as an equally useful alternative.

---

Unfortunately, this didn't ever work for most sites - there's a very specific list we supported:

- chat.meta.stackexchange.com
- chat.askdifferent.com
- chat.seasonedadvice.com
- chat.crossvalidated.com
- chat.stackexchange.com
- chat.askubuntu.com
- chat.stackoverflow.com
- chat.gaming.stackexchange.com
- chat.superuser.com
- chat.serverfault.com
- chat.meta.stackoverflow.com

It wasn't ever "every" site, just the ones that had graduated up until some point in time. However, we are unlikely to revisit this because:

1. It takes effort to set every one up - chat isn't as tied into the site list as some other things.
2. They don't support SSL, because we'd need to make certificate changes to support `chat.*.stackexchange.com` (you can only do a wildcard on the left).

In light of #2, all links not having proper TLS support will be painful once we go [HSTS preload](https://hstspreload.org/) (there are other blockers there - `stackoverflow.com` is likely to go first). In short, it's just not worth supporting - to my knowledge we do not generate these links anywhere - if we do that's a bug and we should address it (please point me to any instance of this!).

For a shortcut though, note that we do support `https://<site>.stackexchange.com/chat` for convenience which hopefully serves (or could serve) your use case. It goes to the general chat site, for instance https://scifi.stackexchange.com/chat goes to https://chat.stackexchange.com/, but maybe it should go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=scifi.stackexchange.com instead.

Would such a change be something we should do?

Comment: Huh. I had a userscript that depended on `chat.<site>.stackexchange.com` URLs for accessing a user's chat profile from their main site profile. Interesting that that was never officially supported. If /chat could redirect to the site chat room list instead, that would make sense and be helpful, thanks!

Comment: If that modification isn't too much work, yes, it would make sense.

Comment: This change has been rolled out, thanks for the feedback!